# Processing IDE unable to read source code files

Tags: java, file, ide, processing, processing-ide

Yesterday I worked on a project, saved the project, and shut off my computer. Today, I tried to open said files but all I got was a blank IDE.

The source code files are stored in a folder along with several `.png` files that are being used for my project. There are 2 source code files corresponding to the 2 tabs I have in my project.

The files are not empty as their size is what you would expect a file containing code to be (1.32 KB and 902b, both being ~80 lines long) so I'm not sure why the IDE cannot open/read them.

I have tried restarting my PC and it has had no effect. Other source code files can be opened normally. If anyone has experienced similar issues any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the content of the files? are they .java files?

Comment: They are .pde files. The content is nothing more than java code, but none of the code is displayed when they are opened in Processing, despite other .pde files working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you opening the files?

Are you double-clicking them from a file explorer? Are you opening the Processing editor and then going to `File -> Open`? Something else?

Note that `.pde` files are just text files, and you can open them up with any text editor. Try opening them up in a basic text editor and checking if the files contain what you expect.

You could try opening Processing up through a command line to see if you see any extra output there. Also you might try uninstalling and reinstalling Processing.

Try with a simpler sketch file. Does that open up okay? Is it a particular part of your code that causes the error? Try to narrow it down to a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can use to reproduce the problem ourselves.

Comment: I have tried double clicking on the .pde files as well as opening them up through the IDE, neither works. I have tried opening up the files in notepad, nothing shows up. I have tried opening other sketches, and they work just fine. It seems like the files are empty, yet they take up the storage space one would expect them too.

Comment: @GrantCridlebaugh If I were you I would then work through the rest of my answer. Can you open them with other editors? Can you put together a [mcve]? Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling Processing?

Comment: I can open the files, but they behave as if they are empty. I have not been able to replicate this, despite my best efforts. Reinstalling Processing did not help. I haven't found anyone else with this same problem, so I'm going to assume this is either rare enough that I don't have to worry about it much or it's something with my hard drive. Either way I'll be fine just reprogramming what I had lost. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @GrantCridlebaugh You can't open them in a basic text editor? If that's the case, then it sounds like the files themselves have been corrupted for some reason. Can you upload the files and post a link?